# How to style parent if child has class in vue?

Tags: vue.js

How to styled parent div if child has class?
I tried use computed with $refs, but $refs.[class] always undefined

**example**

```
<div 
:style="isChildHasClass"
class="container">
    <div class="child example"></div>
</div>
```

how to style div block with class "container", only if child block has class "example"?

Comment: Can you include some code you've tried and explain what is working?

Comment: @PatrickSteele updated

Comment: Have some data or computed property that returns true on false, and based on that value set both your parent/child to have whatever classes/styles you want.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    isExample: true,
  },
  created() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.isExample = !this.isExample
    }, 2000)
  },
  computed: {
    parentClasses() {
      return ['parent', this.isExample ? 'container' : null];
    },
    childClasses() {
      return ['child', this.isExample ? 'example' : null]
    }
  }

})
```

```css
.container {
  background: tomato;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div :class="parentClasses">
    parentClasses: {{parentClasses}}
    <div :class="childClasses">childClasses: {{childClasses}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't at all answer the question asked.